# javascript location.replace doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code:

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
    $formdir=$_POST['dir'];
    $formlink=$_POST['link'];
    $filelink = fopen('/root/wget/wget-download-link.txt',a);
    $filedir = fopen('/root/wget/wget-dir.txt',w);

    fwrite($filedir, $formdir);

    /*
    fwrite($filelink, $formlink."\n");
    exec('touch /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
    exec('echo "'.$dir.'" > /root/wget/wget-dir.txt',$out);
        */

    exec('echo "'.$formlink.'" > /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt');
    exit();
    }
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\" id=\"WgetForm\">";
echo "Download directory:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link:';
echo ("<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"13\" cols=\"62\"></textarea><br><br>");
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="LinkAdded()" name="wget-send" value="Send" id="WgetID"/>';
echo "</form></div>";
echo <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">

function LinkAdded()
    {
            alert("Link has been sucessfully sent to wget, it'll be downloaded soon, check the wget log for the download progress");
            location.replace("wget_log.php");
    }
</script>
HTML;
foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

the `alert` part works it gives me a pop up but after the pop up, it just gives me a blank page. How do I make the `location.replace("wget_log.php");` work?

stackoverflow keeps telling me that I should add more details on my post but I think that's all the details I can give.

Comment: Why not just drop the javascript, and set the `action` of the form to `wget_log.php`, what you're doing makes no sense ?

Comment: because it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of submitting the form by returning `false` from the click handler

```
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="LinkAdded(); return false;" name="wget-send" value="Send" id="WgetID"/>';
```